# 03 Blazer 130,000 miles

Tags: cooling-system, coolant-leak, water-pump, blazer

Hey guys in need for some serious help. After spending 2000 on repairing my 6 MO. Old truck (and not to an acceptable standard), i have a crack down the plastic part that holds in my radiator and im slowly leaking antifreeze. Sometimes it will leak and sometimes it will hold. Now, some important info. i hit a curb, hard. I did frame damage and needed a whole front end assembly. Im thinking the people who worked on it damaged it as well because it now looks as though someone has backed into my truck due to the scratch marks and loose turn signal. This truck did not have a scratch on it before hand. The fan blade is also broken. I can see where the coolant is leaking [image: leak from the bottom]it looks to be where the radiator connects to maybe the water pump? But anyway, i already have spent 2000 on fixing it , and i need to have my facts in order when presenting the damage to the people who did the work on my truck. 1st question and most important, what still needs to be fixed to make sure it will not start over heating (it hasn't overheated once or moved a smudge past the normal temp). I know the big crack down the part that holds the radiator WAS NOT there after i hit the curb, so 2nd do you think the damage occured when i hit the curb (driver front and back side, had to also replace both rims and tires) or, when something or someone backed into my truck. The damage to tbe exterior is on the passenger side so i know it was not caused by hitting the curb. I know this is long and a bit confusing so please ask any questions necessary and thank you so much for any input! Also, i know the answers received are not guaranteed.

Comment: Radiator tanks are plastic, looks like you need a new radiator. That is a steel the core support in your picture, it is what the radiator sits on, usually in rubber bushings.